# Swift enum and CBCharacteristicProperties

Tags: ios, swift, enums, core-bluetooth

While using the CoreBluetooth framework to setup the device as a peripheral manager, I'm running into difficulties with how Swift handles enumerations.

Specifically, the initializer for CBMutableCharacteristic takes an `enum` for the `properties` argument:

```
init!(type UUID: CBUUID!, properties: CBCharacteristicProperties, value: NSData!, permissions: CBAttributePermissions)
```

`CBCharacteristicProperties` is an `Int`-backed enumeration. If using ObjectiveC, the initializer would accept multiple values for `properties` by using the bitwise OR `|` operator. In Swift, the `enum` does not directly allow use of bitwise OR, but one can perform it on the `rawValues` that back the cases:

```
let properties = CBCharacteristicProperties.Read.rawValue | CBCharacteristicProperties.Notify.rawValue
```

Now, `properties` is of type `Int`, which means it can **not** be passed to the above initializer. (`'Int' is not convertible to 'CBCharactersiticProperties'`) Therefore, I attempted to create an instance of the enumeration from the "raw" value:

```
let cbProperties = CBCharacteristicProperties(rawValue: properties)
```

However, at runtime this resolves to `nil`. The `Int` that results from the bitwise OR does not match any of the `enum` cases. Passing `nil` for the `properties` parameter to the initializer results in a runtime error.

Is it possible to accomplish this in Swift?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The syntax is Swift is exactly the same as in Objective C - Use the | character to separate the values -

```
var someCharacteristic=CBMutableCharacteristic(type: CBUUID(string:"someUUID"), 
  properties:CBCharacteristicProperties.Read|CBCharacteristicProperties.Write ,
  value: nil, 
  permissions: CBAttributePermissions.Readable|CBAttributePermissions.Writeable)
```

**Update** 
While this syntax works on iOS with Xcode 6.2 it doesn't work for an OS X target - looks like a bug

Comment: This does not compile. `Extra argument 'string' in call`

Comment: What version of Xcode are you using?  I have 6.2 and it complains if I omit the "string:".

Comment: `let props = CBCharacteristicProperties.Read|CBCharacteristicProperties.Write` also works in playground, but will not compile in project. Any ideas why?

Comment: I created a new single view swift application, added CoreBluetooth framework, imported CoreBluetooth into the swift file and pasted the line from my answer.  It compiles

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74373/discussion-between-brad-and-paulw11).

Comment: Indeed appears to be a bug in the difference between CoreBluetooth on iOS and OS X. `CBCharacteristicProperties` is an `enum` on OS X. It is a `struct` that adopts `RawOptionSetType` on iOS.

Comment: Doesn't work on Swift 3.x for iOS (use Ben's answer instead `properties: [CBCharacteristicProperties.Read,CBCharacteristicProperties.Notify]`

Answer (score 7):

Objective-C:

```
[[CBMutableCharacteristic alloc] initWithType:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:CHARACTERISTIC_UUID]
                                   properties:CBCharacteristicPropertyNotify |
                                   CBCharacteristicPropertyRead
                                   value:nil
                                   permissions:CBAttributePermissionsReadable]
```

Swift:

```
CBMutableCharacteristic(type: CBUUID(string:CHARACTERISTIC_UUID),
                                properties: [CBCharacteristicProperties.Read,CBCharacteristicProperties.Notify],
                                value: nil,
                                permissions: CBAttributePermissions.Readable)
```